# Comma usage in introductory sentence

Tags: commas, comma-splices

Which of these is correct/better?

1) In the Final Argument of the Phaedo, Socrates proves that the soul is immortal by....

2) In the Final Argument of the Phaedo Socrates proves the soul is immortal by ...

3) In the Final Argument of the Phaedo Socrates proves the soul is immortal, by...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two are correct. It is a matter of one's aesthetics, not grammar.
The third one is wrong.